# How to power a 17W T5 Germicidal UVC Lamp?

Tags: power, ac, light, uv, ballast

I recently bought a [SBL 350T Germicidal Lamp](https://store.uvsolutionsforhome.com/product_p/sbl350t.htm) from American Ultraviolet, but have been having some trouble finding out how to power the lamp since I do not have much experience in lighting and the base of the lamp is unique.

After doing some research, I believe I need a ballast and a starter, but am not sure if I need specific ones for this type of lamp because it is not a standard fluorescent light.

The final problem I have is when looking on how to connect the ballast and starter with the bulb most things online have different bases, [such as this](https://www.techintangent.com/fluorescent-light/), so I am wondering how I should connect everything together once I purchase everything I need.

[image][image]

Comment: There is a "Contact us" link at the bottom of the page you linked to.

Comment: Almost as if they made it non-standard so you'd buy their $700 unit.

Comment: That is a standard connector among high power UV lamps (100W). Looks like a low power one in the picture (17W), so maybe it's standard among UV lamps?

Comment: Looks like that connector is more brand specific than anything. Unless you are looking to build it for learning, you probably can't beat the price: https://www.freshwatersystems.com/products/viqua-ba-vt-replacement-ballast-for-uv-systems